# How to shorter SQL function

Tags: sql, oracle, function

Is it possible to shortner your SQL function like in C# or Java with lambda.

```
set serveroutput on;
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION Two(n IN INT) RETURN FLOAT AS
s FLOAT;
Begin
  s:=0;
  FOR i in 0..n LOOP
    s:=s+1 / POWER(2,i);
  END LOOP;
  
  return s;
END Two;
/
Begin
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Two(2));
END;
/
```

This is how my functions looks like, I feel it's kind of long for the job it does.

How could I shortner it ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: no, there is no such thing as lambda in pl/sql

Comment: @jarlh I'm using Oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to shortner your SQL function like in C# or Java with lambda.

No, there is no lambda syntax in PL/SQL.

> How could I shortner it ?

You can just use 2 - 2<sup>-n</sup>:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION Two(n IN INT) RETURN FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN 2 - POWER(2,-n);
END Two;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9e3f96eda304230a835acb4279a563a1)*